# App crashed due to memory warning when setting contentScaleType

Tags: ios, swift, scale, cgcontext, zooming

I am working on an App where I am using CGContext to create squares, circles and lines. When I am zooming in I am setting ImageView's subviews **contentScaleFactor**.

Code :

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
  for view in (imageView?.subviews)! {
                view.contentScaleFactor = scale;
                view.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
 }
```

But When this code executes, **App terminated due to memory warning.** When I comments particular line (view.contentScaleFactor = scale;) App runs perfectly.

Any Solution for this??

Comment: Are you sure that setting view.contentScaleFactor will not provoke recursive calls to scrollViewDidEndZooming ?

Comment: Yes,, this is the complete code in scrollViewDidEndZooming.

Comment: Ok. And why you need to change contentScaleFactor ? According to Apple docs `In general, you should not need to modify the value in this property. ` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622657-contentscalefactor

Comment: If you put the stack trace will be easier to understand the issue. My guess is that you are force unwrapping something.

Comment: @AntonMalmygin I need to it to scale my views with transform value of scrollview .

Comment: @Andrea These is nothing in Stack trace. Its just crashing due to memory issue.

Comment: What is the largest value of `scale` that you can use? 2GB of RAM and fullscreen view of 375x667 points should at most be able to handle `sqrt( 2147483648 / ( 375 * 667 * 4)) ≈ 46` before running out of RAM. That is given you only have one view and nothing else uses any RAM.

Comment: Maximum value is 10.0 for scale

Answer (score 0):

Use  `view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, scale, scale);` instead of `view.contentScaleFactor`.

Comment: No, not working.. I am using contentScaleFactor because my CGContext lines are getting blurred on zooming of UIScrollview.

Comment: By using contentScaleFactor they are just scaled and not got blurred

Comment: I think you misuse contentScaleFactor, because it designed to be about 1.0 or 2.0 depending on device capabilities, so this is not dynamic parameter, as I can see. What happens if you set it to some fix reasonable value (like 2.0 or 4.0) (during initialisation, for example) and after apply normal zooming ?